# Highlight text criteria in Sql Server full text search

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, full-text-search

Regarding this [SQL Server Full text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775582/how-to-save-documents-like-pdf-docx-xls-in-sql-server-2008) topic, I could save my files in binary data type and my problem was solved.

Now, after saving files in the database I have a new problem.

After searching, I need to find the location of the criteria (For example in which lines or which columns) and highlight those.

I suppose this is very important that we can find the location of the criteria text in files and show them to the users.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662419/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-the-match-in-a-formsof-inflectional-full-text-searc

Answer (score 0):

Till SQL Server 2005, I don't think there is any built-in function for this.

Anyways, check out Christopher Felpel (VB.NET based) solution for highlighting the search string - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/2e18958f-cdb9-4689-8a88-0af471963479

Answer (score 0):

I needed this code and called Christopher to get.  He posted it on his site  It can be downloaded from the message [.Net Search Result Highlighter for SQL Full-Text Search](http://christopherfelpel.com/2013/03/16/net-search-result-highlighter-for-sql-full-text-search/)

I used it and it is working good